# BigCommerce Page Builder Widgets - Can i set different default content to each of my starting items in an array?

Tags: widget, bigcommerce

I am creating widget templates and have an array in my schema that allows the user to select some images and text to build the widget out in the front end.

Here is my schema for that particular part:

```
"schema": [
       {
            "type": "array",
            "label": "Items",
            "id": "items",
            "defaultCount": 6,
            "entryLabel": "Item",
            "schema": [
                {
                    "type": "tab",
                    "label": "Main Image",
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "settings": [
                            {
                                "type": "boolean",
                                "label": "Image Visible?",
                                "id": "image-visible",
                                "default": true
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "Image",
                                "type": "imageManager",
                                "id": "mainImage",
                                "default": {
                                            "src": "exampleimage.jpg",
                                            "type": "imageManager"
                                        },
                                "conditional": {
                                    "key": "image-visible",
                                    "operator": "IN",
                                    "value": [
                                        true
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "tab",
                    "label": "CTA",
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "settings": [
                            {
                                    "type": "boolean",
                                    "label": "Button Visible?",
                                    "id": "button-visible",
                                    "default": true
                                },
                        {
                                    "label": "CTA",
                                    "type": "input",
                                    "id": "buttonText",
                                    "default": "Shop Now",
                                    "conditional": {
                                        "key": "button-visible",
                                        "operator": "IN",
                                        "value": [
                                            true
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "CTA URL",
                                    "type": "input",
                                    "id": "buttonURL",
                                    "default": "/example-product",
                                    "conditional": {
                                        "key": "button-visible",
                                        "operator": "IN",
                                        "value": [
                                            true
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "tab",
                    "label": "Secondary Image",
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "settings": [
                            {
                                    "type": "boolean",
                                    "label": "Secondary Image Visible?",
                                    "id": "secondary-visible",
                                    "default": true
                                },
                        {
                                    "label": "Secondary Image",
                                    "type": "imageManager",
                                    "id": "secondary-image",
                                    "default": {
                                            "src": "emaple2.jpg?",
                                            "type": "imageManager"
                                        },
                                    "conditional": {
                                        "key": "secondary-visible",
                                        "operator": "IN",
                                        "value": [
                                            true
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "tab",
                    "label": "Text",
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "settings": [
                            {
                                    "type": "boolean",
                                    "label": "Text Visible?",
                                    "id": "text-visible",
                                    "default": true
                                },
                        {
                                    "label": "Text",
                                    "type": "input",
                                    "id": "text",
                                    "default": "product copy.",
                                    "conditional": {
                                        "key": "text-visible",
                                        "operator": "IN",
                                        "value": [
                                            true
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

My client wants to have a default number of array items set to 6. Currently the default content (images and text) is the same across all the items. My question is: can i set individual default config so that each one of the default 6 items has different config? This way every time the widget is used it will have a starting point that is easier to work from.

Currently the default is set on the individual parts of the array items, i would like to set some more general config that dictates the default 6 items individually.